# Input File Length in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I want to get the number of files selected for input file. In HTML, I have:

```
<input id="photoFile" type="file" name="pictures" multiple="multiple"/>
```

Im using JQuery and I have:

```
$('#photoFile').get(0).files.length;
```

But I found out this is not a solution for Internet Explorer. It works in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera. How to make it work also in IE 8+?

Comment: I think you need to use a bit of Flash to choose multiple files with the older IEs.

Comment: consider to use SWFUpload .

Answer (score 1):

even IE9 does not support HTML5 File API and therefore it returns undefined value for files property.

Answer (score 0):

It's [File API](http://caniuse.com/fileapi), it's not supported in IE 8 & IE 9.

Comment: are there other ways instead of using the File API?

Comment: Use third party upload plugin, e.g.: [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/), [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)

Answer (score 0):

As the File API is [not supported in IE9](http://caniuse.com/#search=file), you can have a try with this [Polyfill](https://github.com/moxiecode/moxie) on Github.