# object is null or undefined error in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, internet-explorer-9

So I followed some tutorials for uploading files asynchronously. The project runs fine for Mozilla Firefox and Chrome, but when i run it in Internet Explorer 9 it gives an error:

```
0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'length': object is null or undefined
```

here is where it shows the error:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnUpload").click(OnUpload);
    });    
function OnUpload(evt) {
        var files = $("#fileUpload").get(0).files;
        if (files.length > 0) {        <---//Error
    ...
```

I have already tried some fixes e.g adding this to the head tag

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >
```

This doesn't work for me.
So help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14845895/3639582 File API is not supported in <IE10

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what jQuery plugin you're using for the file upload, but my guess is that it's one which is using a browser feature (File API) that isn't available in older browsers like IE9.

There are ways of uploading files using old browsers; if you want to support IE9, you'll have to use one of the older techniques.

You might want to look at [some of the libraries listed here](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#file-api) -- this is a list of "Polyfill" libraries which claim to allow some degree of compatibility for this new feature in older browsers. I can't guarantee that any of them will work nicely with your existing jQuery plugin, but they should at least give you a starting point for getting the feature working.